# find $I=\int_0^{\infty} \log{(x+1/x)}\,\frac{dx}{1+x^2} $

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Using $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \log\sin x\,\mathrm dx= -\dfrac{\pi}{2} \log 2$$
how to find

$$I=\int_0^{\infty} \log{(x+1/x)}\,\frac{dx}{1+x^2}. $$

Putting $x=\tan z$,

$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} (\log 2-\log(\sin(2z)))dz=\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2-1/2\int_0^{\pi} \log(\sin(u))du$ for $2z=u$

what to do next?

Comment: Split the integral into two pieces and make a substitution $u=2z$ in the second integral.

Comment: limit becomes 0 to $\pi$ for the second integral

Comment: So? I hope you are aware that $$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}dx\,\log\sin x=2\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}dx\,\log\sin x$$

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for information about the kinds of posts we look for on this site. This post lacks key information such as the source and motivation of the problem. You can edit the post to add these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the second integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi}\log(\sin(u)) du = \int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(u)) du + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\log(\sin(u)) du$$

And use a change of variable $u=\pi-x$ for the second part.

Answer (score 2):

You are given that ; $\int_0^\frac\pi2 \log(\sin(x))\,dx = -\frac\pi2\log 2$

$ I=\int_0^{\pi/2} (\log 2-\log(\sin(2z)))dz$

$I = \int_0^\frac\pi2\log 2\,dz-\int_0^\frac\pi2\log(\sin(2z))\,dz$

Consider $J = \int_0^\frac\pi2\log(\sin(2z))\,dz $

let $2z =w\implies dz=\frac{dw}2$

$J= \frac12\int_0^\pi\log(\sin(w))\,dw$

$J=\frac12\cdot2\int_0^\frac\pi2\log(\sin(w))\,dw$

$J = \int_0^\frac\pi2\log(\sin(w))\,dw$

$J = -\frac\pi2\log(2)  $

Therefore ,$I = \log2\cdot z\big|_0^\frac\pi2+\frac\pi2\log(2)$

$I =2\cdot\frac\pi2\log(2) $

$I =\pi\log(2)$